# How to count lines containing a search term with notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I want to find the number of lines containing a search term and ignore duplicates on the same line.

Comment: I found out that I can use the Analyze Plugin to do this, but I'd still like to know if there is a regex I can use instead.

Comment: I just found this regex for multiple search terms ^.*(Foo|man|choo).*$

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try this out:

1. Issue Ctrl+F
2. Under search mode, select "Regular expression"
3. In your search term, type `<your search term>.*$` (It is assumed that your search term contains only alphanumeric characters. You may need to perform necessary escape if your search term contains symbol.)
4. Select Count and the number of lines containing the search term will be displayed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, thx. What does the dot (.) do in this expression?

Comment: It refers to any character in regex. Therefore it will perform an greedy match when `.` and `*` is used together. Please mark it as accepted if this answer works for you :)

Answer (score 4):

If you want to count the number of lines that contain `foo` but not `foobar` you have to use word boundary `\b`:

```
`\bfoo\b.*$`
```

In order to search multiple patterns:

```
^(?=.*\bfoo\b)(?=.*\bbar\b)(?=.*\bbaz\b)
```

Comment: thx. What would I need to add to the search expression to perform a multiple keyword search where every term is present?